# Powershell remote enabling

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

I am not able to connect to remote machine using powershell. The procedures i did is:

1. Enable-PSRemoting -Force
2. Set-Item WSMan:\localhost\Client\TrustedHosts *
3. restart-Service winrm
4. Enter-PSSession IpAddress

When i run the last step (4th one) from my server machine i am getting an error like:

> Enter-PSSession :  Connecting to
>   remote server failed with the
>   following error message : Access is
>   denied.

I have tried all the above 4 steps in both client and server machine. Please help

Thanks
Prav

Answer (score 3):

Check the port on the remote machine

> PS Z:> cd WSMan:\localhost\Listener
>  PS WSMan:\localhost\Listener> dir
>  [cut]
>  PS WSMan:\localhost\Listener> cd .\Listener_1084132640
>  PS WSMan:\localhost\Listener\Listener_1084132640> dir
>  WSManConfig: 
> Microsoft.WSMan.Management\WSMan::localhost\Listener\Listener_1084132640
>  Name Value
>  ---- -----
>  Address *
>  Transport HTTP
>  Port 5985

Then connect with the correct port

> $remotePowerShellPort = 5985
>   $ConnectionURI = ("http://{0}:{1}" -f $targetServer, $remotePowerShellPort)
>   $remoteSession = New-PSSession -ConnectionURI $ConnectionURI
>   Invoke-Command -Session $remoteSession -ScriptBlock { dir } 
>   Remove-PSSession $remoteSession

Comment: how will i know powershell port